# Can Footnotes reside in another file?

Tags: footnotes, external-files

I want to know if is there a possibility/method/package, by which I can uniquely label all footnote positions in `book.tex`. And another file, `footnote.tex`, containing the footnotes
and matching labels, which can be used for inserting footnotes?

Example:

`blah blah blah\footnotemark{id1} blah blah\footnotemark{id2}` in `chap1.tex`; 
`\footnotetext{id1}{blah blah},\footnotetext{id2}{blah blah blah}` in `chap1foot.tex`. When `chap1.tex` is ran I need `\footnotetext{id1}{blah blah}` to appear with footnote counter starting from 1 in each page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want the footnote texts to be in another file? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes I need footnote text in another file, But appear as normal footnotes in output i.e. each page footnote counter starts from 1.

Comment: The main risk of this approach is losing the correspondence between the footnotes; it very hard to maintain if you need to add a footnote between two others.

Comment: The syntax is `\footnotemark[<num>]` since `<num>` is assigned to a *counter*. Please elaborate on the following: Are you creating the file `chap1.tex` and `chap1foot.tex` separately, or do you want this to be automated? Do you want the footnotes to appear on the actual pages that you have the accompanying `\footnotemark`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`sepfootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package. Here is an example of its basic usage:

```
% to keep this example self-contained
% the file that contains the footnotes:
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-notes.tex}
\Anotecontent{id1}{\label{id1}This is the footnote with id1.}
\Anotecontent{id2}{\label{id2}This is the footnote with id2.}
\Anotecontent{id3}{This is the footnote with id3.}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
% this defines new footnotes and the commands
%   \Anotecontent{<id>}{<text>}
%   \Anote{<id>}
% and a few more:
\newfootnotes{A}

% input the footnote definitions:
\input{\jobname-notes}

% just for this example:
\textheight=80pt

\begin{document}

A text\Anote{id1} with some footnotes\Anote{id2} to demonstrate how
`sepfootnotes' works.\footnotemark[\ref{id1}] In order to make
this\Anote{id3} a bit longer here's another\footnotemark[\ref{id2}]
sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have appreciated your response. What is the difference between using or not using `\label{idN}`?

Comment: @A.Cedano the same as always: with a label the footnote can be referenced as I showed in the example

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I just implemented it and it works great.