# Move the footnote text away from the footnote command in code

Tags: tables, footnotes, code

I have some text with a couple of footnotes in tables which I handle with the `footnote` package. The footnote text is very very long and it makes the code unreadable, it happened already that I had to bisect the entire code to find small syntax error in tables which I missed because of the really ugly code.

Is it possible to move the footnote text away from the footnote command in code?

I know already about the `footnotemark-footnotetext` solution, but I would like a general solution that could be used for other commands to. For example with hyperlinks and similar stuff. Is there any way to achieve this?

What I would like is something like this (this is not real code):

```
\begin{document}

main text here\footnote{1}
more main text\footnote{2}
more text\href{3}{name}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% footnote contents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[1] footnote 1 text
[2] footnote 2 text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% email addresses
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[3] mailto:mail@server.com

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [`sepfootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package, see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77852/5049) to “[Can Footnotes reside in another file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76474/5049)”

Comment: Yes this is the way to go, but does it work only with footnotes? Is there a way to a generalized approach for other commands to? The footnote case is the most common, but this may be useful elsewhere too.

Comment: @marcinkus Have a look at [Is it possible to write all mathematical formulas in a separate file and add them in main file on-demand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87095/5049). The methods outlined there should easily be adapted to other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out what you probably already know: that if you don't want email addresses cluttering the main body of your text, you can factor them out just by using vanilla LaTeX macros, like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\harryemail{mailto:harry@server.com}
\def\sallyemail{mailto:sally@server.com}

\begin{document}

Email \href{\harryemail}{Harry} or \href{\sallyemail}{Sally}

\end{document}
```