# Thesis to paper (journal)

Tags: thesis, journal-publishing, journal

I have a big thesis document (say: thesis.tex) from which I would like to publish parts in a journal (say: in paper.tex).

Is there a possibility to indicate parts in the thesis, such that these appear in my paper.tex document?

---

I am thinking of something like this in thesis.tex:

```
\begin{}

 Example text 

\end{}
```

such that this (''Example text'') then appears in paper.tex (paper.pdf).

Comment: Use `clipboard`.  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142867/11604).

Comment: depending on how a publisher handles refereeing and production, a pdf file produced with sections "commented out" may pass muster and be accepted by referees, but the publisher's production staff won't appreciate having large chunks of a file "invisible" on the output.  it's easy, in that situation, to make mistakes, and you could end up with material published that you had no intention of including.  sorry to say, if you're submitting for publication, it's best to have just the intended content included in your file.

Comment: Is there any news here?