# foonotes in external page

Tags: footnotes

I would like to insert footnotes in a file external to the text which is:

```
main.tex
  |_img
  |____tex-file
  |      |______chapter1.tex
  |      |______%notes.tex
  |
  |................
```

I tried using this [method](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Footnotes)

```
For instance\footnotemark I can use the same footnote more than 
once\footnotemark[\value{footnote}].
 
\footnotetext{footnote with two references}
```

that I found interesting because it allows you to manage the notes at the bottom of the page. this is the most comfortable way because it leaves the reference text clean.

my intention to have more control is to move the notes to a new page and then to a new note.tex file.
[image]
this file must contain only the strings concerning the foonotes, but it must not be printed
it's possible? could you give me valid suggestions?

----------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------

I open a new file so-called notes.tex and with this method, is created a "database" that contains only the footnotes :

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Mathesymbole
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\input{mydef}

\begin{document}
%<*notes001> %% TAG 
\footnote{
 Se \textbf{dS} copre tutta la superficie del volume $\Vm$, il corrispondente $\Delta{V}$ costruito sopra il dS, copre l'intero volume $\Delta{V}$ con segno giusto; Allora l'integrale in V può essere sostituito con l'integrale in S}.
%</notes001>
\end{document}
```

in the preamble I insert the command :

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
    \newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
        \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
    }
```

in this way I can use the `\loadnote` command in any other file recalling the footnote that interests me and in the right position.
for example : `\loadnote{001}`
the note is shown at the bottom of the page and with the correct numbering

Comment: So you don't want the footnotes to be printed at all? And what should happen to the in text references (the marks)? Should they be printed or not?

Comment: @Skillmon the footnotes must be printed, the one that is not printed is the file containing the text references. I would like to exploit an external file as if it were a database of footnotes. I'm using this method for the equations that are chased with a `\loadeq` command such as : `\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}`
`\newcommand{\loadeq}[1]{%
 \ExecuteMetaData[equations.tex]{eq#1}%
}`

Comment: I still don't get it. You say they must be printed, but those not printed should be in the file?! Should the file be generated from your footnotes? Or do you have a file which holds specific strings that should not show up in footnotes? I'm totally lost here.

Comment: Maybe this help: [How do others manage their footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142801/how-do-others-manage-their-footnotes)

Comment: @Fran Your answer is very interesting and I want to see if it will be more effective than mine.

Comment: Try the `sepfootnotes` package. It supports a database of footnotes in a separate `notes.tex` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `sepfootnotes` documentation:

## notes.tex

```
\anotecontent{Plato}{Socrates's pupil.}
```

## doc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{a}
\input{notes}
\begin{document}
This was first brought up by the great Plato.\anote{Plato}
\end{document}
```