# Use external file for database equation

Tags: equations, tags

I created an external reference file with many mathematical formulas.
very similar to this:  [foonotes in external page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454073/foonotes-in-external-page)
the **equations.tex** is so structured :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{stackengine}  %% barbII
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\newcommand{\for}{\text{for }}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \underline{\textit{Principio di conservazione della massa }}: 
%<*eq001>
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq001}
    \textbf{m} = \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho(x,t)\de{V} 
    \end{equation}
\end{center}
%</eq001>

%<*eq002>
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq002}
    \Dtot{m}{t} =\Dtot{}{t} \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho(x,t)\de{V}  = 0 
    \end{equation}
\end{center}
%</eq002>

\item \underline{\textit{Principio di bilancio della quantità di moto}} (Eulero, 1752):

%<*eq003>
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq003}
    \textbf{q}  = \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho\textbf{u}\de{V}  
    \end{equation}
\end{center}
%</eq003>
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the preamble of the **main.tex** i inserted this:

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand{\loadeq}[1]{%
    \ExecuteMetaData[equations.tex]{eq#1}%
}
```

I call the various formulas in **chapter01.tex** with the loadeq {equation number} command :

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

\loadeq{003}
```

[image]

***the problem is born if:***

- I want to align two equations; `\loadeq{003} = \loadeq{003}`
- I want to align the equation and a text; `ciao =  \loadeq{003}`
- I want to align a particular symbol with the equation. `$\vec{\Pi}=$ \loadeq{003}`
  [image]

It would be interesting to understand how to be able to concatenate different `\loadeq{arg}`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should structure your equations. No need of `catchfilebetweentags`.

In the following, if you call `\useeq*{<number>}`, both sides of the saved equation are typeset; with `\useeq{<number>}`, only the right-hand side. In case of need, this could be easily augmented with `\useeq[<side>]{<number>}` where `<side>` is either `l` or `r` to print the left-hand side or the right-hand side.

```
\begin{filecontents}{antonio-equations}
\EQ{001}{
  \mathbf{p} = \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho(x,t)\de{V}
}
\EQ{002}{
  \Dtot{m}{t} = \Dtot{}{t} \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho(x,t)\de{V}
}
\EQ{003}{
  \mathbf{q} = \Intlim{V_{m}}\rho\mathbf{u}\de{V}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\EQ}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_antonio_eq_#1_prop }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antonio_eq_temp_seq { = } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_antonio_eq_#1_prop }
   { l } { \seq_item:Nn \l__antonio_eq_temp_seq { 1 } }
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_antonio_eq_#1_prop }
   { r } { \seq_item:Nn \l__antonio_eq_temp_seq { 2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\useeq}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanT { #1 }
   {
    \prop_item:cn { g_antonio_eq_#2_prop } { l } =
   }
  \prop_item:cn { g_antonio_eq_#2_prop } { r }
 }
\seq_new:N \l__antonio_eq_temp_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\de}[1]{\mathop{}\!d#1}
\newcommand{\Dtot}[2]{\frac{\de{#1}}{\de{#2}}}
\newcommand{\Intlim}[1]{\int\limits_{#1}}

\input{antonio-equations} % load the equations

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Principio di conservazione della massa}: 
\begin{gather}
\useeq*{001} \label{eq001}
\\
\useeq*{002}=0 \label{eq002}
\end{gather}

\item \textit{Principio di bilancio della quantità di moto} (Eulero, 1752):
\begin{equation}
\useeq*{003} \label{eq003}
\end{equation}

\item Combiniamo
\begin{align}
  \vec{\Pi} &= \useeq{001}
  \\
  x &= \useeq{003}
\end{align}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Please, don't underline text in italic: double emphasis is too much and underlining is a frowned upon device among typographers.

[image]

Note also that you should never surround `equation` by `center`. And *never* should be taken in its literal sense. Also consecutive `equation` environments are to be avoided: `amsmath` offers a wealth of display environments.

Comment: I was looking for this solution. this is very interesting.
It's the first time I've written complete notes in LaTex and there's a lot to learn

Comment: I could ask you for an explanation of all sequence of commands : `\ExplSyntaxOn ....\prop...\seq....... \ExplSyntaxOff`.  how come it signals it as an unrecognized command?

Comment: and have problems with commands `\Aboxed`. have a error : **Misplaced alignment tab character &. \Aboxed{\barbII{\tau} =\useeqq*{010}}**. I replaced with `\boxed` command, with this i dont'have problems

Comment: @Antonio I can say nothing from this small snippet.

Comment: Regarding the first question (the explanation on the sequences of commands), it is the code that you put me.
The second request, tomorrow I look if I can say more.

Comment: @Antonio For the first question: update your TeX system.