# problem with hspace

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

I noticed now a space problem with hspace, especially the command:

```
\newcommand{\Div}[1]{\displaystyle \boldsymbol{\nabla}\hspace{-.1em}\cdot\hspace{-.1em} #1}
```

[image]
how could it be solved, keeping the same formalism?

external [note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454073/foonotes-in-external-page/454392#454392) :

```
%<*notes012>  
\footnote{ricordando che se $\Div{u}=0$ allora $\barbII{\tau}=-\textbf{p}\I+2\mu\barbII{e}$}
%</notes012>
```

---

```
L'equazione  costitutiva per fluidi newtoniani \eqref{eq062}, può essere espressa nella sua forma per componenti\loadnote{012}:

\begin{equation}\label{eq063}
\begin{aligned}
    \tau_{ij}=-\textbf{p}\delta_{ij}+2\mu\left( \eij-\Fra{1}{3}e_{kk}\delta_{ij}\right) 
    \text{dove $\delta_{ij}$ = }~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
    1&\rightarrow& \text{se i = j;}\\
    0&\rightarrow& \text{se i $\neq$ j};\\
    \end{array}\right.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[right node/.style={rectangle,draw}]
 node{%
        $\begin{aligned}
            \tikzmarknode{ex1}e_{kk}\tikzmarknode{ex2}=tr(\barbII{e})=\tikzmarknode{ex3}\Div{u}
        \end{aligned}$};

    \draw[->,>=latex]([shift={(-70pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:ex1-ex2) |- ++(80pt,-25pt) node[right,text width=6cm] 
    { Considera la somma degli elementi della diagonale di $\barbII{e}$ e non coinvolge gli elementi ij;};
    \draw[->,>=latex]([shift={(-8pt,-15pt)}]pic cs:ex3) |- ++(16pt,-52pt) node[right,text width=6cm] 
    {Velocità di Deformazione Volumetrica (Comprimibiltà);};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the `\nabla}\hspace{-.1em}\cdot\hspace{-.1em}`  has different distances. when it is inserted in the command `\begin{tikzpicture}....` the distances are not respected
[image]

Comment: @marmot i know this but my question concerns a `\newcomman ......\ nabla \ cdot. ..` .  why are not the distances kept?

Comment: @Antonio: Can you provide a complete example that compiles? You can remove all the unnecessary stuff like `\eij`, `\Fra`, `\loadnote`, ... since they have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Well, you are nesting `tikzpicture`s, which [should be avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66037/121799). Then I am not sure if you are using the correct syntax for `\tikzmarknode`, it is `\tikzmarknode{<label>}{<content>}`, yet you are using it in the same way as the (old) `\tikzmark` command. And, as pointed out by @Werner, you do not provide us with the definitions. Please write an MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be an answer (but given that you do not provide us with some compilable code, this is the best I can do at this point). This version

- avoids nesting `tikzpicture`s and
- uses `\tikzmarknode` in an arguably more appropriate way.

Apart from that, I *guess*ed what your macros are doing. And I removed redundancies (why are you adding `aligned` here, you were not using it).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\Div}[1]{\displaystyle \boldsymbol{\nabla}\!\cdot\! #1}
\newcommand{\eij}[0]{\ensuremath{e_{ij}}}
\newcommand{\Fra}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\barbII}[1]{\underset{=}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \tau_{ij}&=-\boldsymbol{p}\delta_{ij}+2\mu\left( \eij-\Fra{1}{3}e_{kk}\delta_{ij}\right) 
    \text{dove $\delta_{ij}$ = }~\begin{cases}
    1&\rightarrow \text{se}~i = j;\\
    0&\rightarrow \text{se}~i\neq j;
    \end{cases}\label{eq063}\\
    \tikzmarknode{ex1}{e_{kk}}&=\tr(\barbII{e})=\Div{\tikzmarknode{ex3}{u}} 
\end{align}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[right node/.style={rectangle,draw},overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[-latex]([yshift=-1pt]ex1.south) |- ++(86pt,-25pt) 
    node[right,text width=6cm] (cons)
    { Considera la somma degli elementi della diagonale di $\barbII{e}$ e non coinvolge gli elementi ij;};
    \draw[-latex,preaction={draw,white,ultra thick,-}]([yshift=-1pt]ex3.south) -- ++(0,-60pt) coordinate(aux)
    -- (aux -| cons.west) node[right,text width=6cm] 
    {Velocit\'a di Deformazione Volumetrica (Comprimibilt\'a);};
\end{tikzpicture}

blah blah\footnote{ricordando che se $\Div{u}=0$ allora $\barbII{\tau}=-\boldsymbol{p}
\boldsymbol{I}+2\mu\barbII{e}$} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Velocit**à**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/velocita/) not Velocit**á**

Comment: my problem was related to the distance between `\nabla`, `\cdot` and `u`. now it works properly. I'm learning to use latex and I find many interesting difficulties. some with the time I'm starting to solve them. others must study the contents and acquire the right mentality

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want the negative space in order to reduce the distance between the centered dot and the symbols at both sides.

Using the `em` unit is wrong to begin with, because it depends on the text font current at the time the formula started. In a `tikzpicture` the font might be `\nullfont` for which the em unit corresponds to zero and, in any case, it is not generally predictable.

Beware also of `\displaystyle` which serves no real purpose for typesetting “nabla+centered dot+variable” *and* will make damage to the rest of the formula.

My choice would be, loading also the `bm` package *after* `amsmath` (the package provides for a better replacement of `\boldsymbol` called `\bm`, but allows `\boldsymbol` as a synonym for `\bm`, so your code need not be changed):

```
\newcommand{\Div}{\bm{\nabla}\!\cdot\!}
```

The `\!` command inserts some negative space using “math units”, which are independent on the current text font. There's no need to use an argument; however, `\Div u` and `\Div{u}` would do the same.

You should also avoid `\textbf` in formulas for *math* symbols: the correct command is `\mathbf` as this will not be affected by font parameters (shape, for instance) current at the time the formula started out.

By the way, input such as

```
\text{dove $\delta_{ij}$ = }~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
    1&\rightarrow& \text{se i = j;}\\
    0&\rightarrow& \text{se i $\neq$ j};\\
```

is incorrect under many respects. It should be

```
\text{dove }\delta_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{se $i = j$;} \\
  0 & \text{se $i \neq j$;}
\end{cases}
```

I've never seen an arrow between the value for the case and the condition; however, this is not the main point. The letters “i” and “j” denote the very same object as in the subscript to `\delta`, so they must be typeset in the same way, that is, math italic.

As a stylistic remark, the “Kronecker delta” is so widespread a symbol that it should not be explained as part of a more important explanation: this is very distracting. Define the symbol beforehand and use it without explicit mention.

A grammatical note: `Velocit\'a` typesets an acute accent whereas it should be a *grave* accent. Thus `` Velocit\`a ``. Or, why not exploiting modern operating systems and type `Velocità`?

Comment: yes, the arrow is a formalism that I use in my notes. maybe it's not formally correct. This is my first document written entirely in latex. I'm rewriting some notes from my professor's lectures.

Comment: if I insert the `bm` package with the command you suggested, I receive many errors. many commands have been written to `\boldsymbol` (I definitely use it erroneously). what I have written up to now everything should be corrected, even the preamble. unfortunately I have no one to help me in this. By doing the many tests I have done, I have certainly created many errors that I can not correct.

Comment: [Velocit**à**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/velocita/) not Velocit**á**