# problem with text formatting \ itemize

Tags: equations, footnotes, itemize, text-manipulation

I looked for a command to improve the equation item and I met [this one](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7195).

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
newcommand{\itemEq}[1]{%
         \begingroup%
         \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
         \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
         \parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\begin{flalign}#1&&\end{flalign}}%
         \endgroup}
```

working with the command I noticed that it has problems recalling the [foonotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454073/foonotes-in-external-page) but also with the format of the text, such as in this case:

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[d)]\itemEq{\Dtot{\ui}{t}=\Dpar{\ui}{t}+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\Dpar{\ui}{x_j}\uj = \uit+\ui\cdot\uij:\text{Derivata Lagrangiana  della componente i-esima della velocità}}  

\end{itemize}
```

the text is very long and I can not go to the next line

[image]

-----------------------UPDATE---------------------------

I found the solution :

```
\item[d)]\itemEq{\Dtot{\ui}{t}=\Dpar{\ui}{t}+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\Dpar{\ui}{x_j}\uj = \uit+\ui\cdot\uij:\text{\parbox{5cm}{Derivata Lagrangiana  della componente i-esima della velocità}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need an equation number?

Comment: @Bernard I would like to divide the text into two lines

Comment: That is easy, but why do you use the `flalign` environment?

Comment: @Bernard Because it seemed appropriate. but I do not think so.

Comment: What so you try to achieve? An equation in \displaystyle, and some explanation afterwards, beginning on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the equation and set the text in the remaining space with some clearance. But my preference would be to state the description and then display the equation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newsavebox{\eqdescbox}

\newcommand{\eqdesc}[2]{%
  \sbox{\eqdescbox}{$\displaystyle #1$}%
  \usebox{\eqdescbox}\hfill
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em-\wd\eqdescbox}{\raggedright #2}%
}

\newcommand{\Dtot}[2]{\frac{D#1}{D#2}}
\newcommand{\Dpar}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item \eqdesc{
  \Dtot{u_i}{t}=\Dpar{u_i}{t}+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\Dpar{u_i}{x_j}u_j =
  u_it+u_i\cdot u_{ij}
}{Derivata Lagrangiana  della componente $i$-esima della velocità}

\item Derivata Lagrangiana  della componente $i$-esima della velocità
\begin{equation*}
  \Dtot{u_i}{t}=\Dpar{u_i}{t}+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\Dpar{u_i}{x_j}u_j =
  u_it+u_i\cdot u_{ij}
\end{equation*}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I don't think you gain too much by typing `\ui` over `u_i`: it's error prone and forces you to remember too many commands.

[image]

Comment: I have a problem of displaying the braces and with the subscript: `u_i, u_ i, ij, i, u_ {j, ij} ... etc. etc`. I was forced to write the synthetic commands, equations. In TeXStudio I did not find a way to have a different color in the brackets, I often find the code boring.

Answer (score 2):

I can propose this, based on `tabularx`. Not having your macros, I loaded the `diffcoeff` package to simplify typing of derivatives.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, diffcoeff}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), start=4]
\item
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}|}
\Diff{u_i}{t}=\diffp{u_i}{t}+∑_{j=1}^{3}\diffp{u_i}{x_j}u_j = u_{i, t} +u_i \cdot u_{i, j} :
& Derivata Lagrangiana della componente i-esima della velocità.
\end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]