# Import footnotes from one file

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

Like as bibtex is there anyway to import footnote from one tex files. What I come up with is

```
%--------------------------------------------Footnote references from label
\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
```

and put a level in each reference

```
here\footnote{\label{note1}This is the labeled footnote}
```

and furthermore call the footnote with the label name as follows

```
Here\footnoteref{note1}
```

By adding like this footnote automatically visible in the first case. This approach is appropriate if I want to refer same footnote in multiple places. What I basically want is **like as bibtex add the footnote with specific ID or reference name ?** Thanks and any suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: seems to me that you have re-invented `\footref`: [Reference different places to the same footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote/74668#74668). You might also be interested in [Can Footnotes reside in another file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76474/can-footnotes-reside-in-another-file)

Comment: The pack­age 'sep­foot­note­' sup­ports foot­notes and end­notes from sep­a­rate files.

Comment: Also probably interesting: the [`fixfoot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixfoot) package